# My module doesn´t appear in System->Configuration->Advanced

Tags: module

I´m following this Magento tutorial:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-3.html

But when I reach **"Create Hello World Module"**, the last point, I can´t see my module in **System->Configuration->Advanced**.

I have followed correctly the tutorial and I tried some Internet solutions, but I can´t find it yet.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: check the file is exist or not in app/etc/modules/yourmodule.xml

Comment: Can you list out the path of Package_Module.xml and its content?

Comment: Information posted in own answer

Comment: @MarcGregori, you have followed the link of Magento 1.x while you are creating the module for Magento 2.x.

Comment: If possible, please upvote or accept any answer (by Sukumar Gorai or by Me).

Answer (score 0):

1. Please add  at the begining of the xml and flush the magento cache. – Sukumar Gorai

I added "`<?xml version="1.0"?>`" to:

/app/etc/modules/Magentotutorial_Helloworld.xml
/app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Helloworld/etc/config.xml

next step:

```
./bin/magento cache:clean
./bin/magento cache:flush
```

But nothing happened...

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Are you using Magento 2?

Comment: I´m using Magento 2.1.9

Comment: @MarcGregori, you have followed the link of Magento 1.x while you are creating the module for Magento 2.x.

Comment: Then you are following wrong steps to create module as magento2 doesn't store module files on app/code/local. Also there is no app/etc/modules in magento2. You are following magento1 structure.

Comment: Oh my god... Sometimes I think that the State should give me a payment for keep me alive... Thanks a lot for your help. I will be more carefully the next time.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment of yours, the link you have followed is wrong.

Since you are creating the module for Magento 2.1.9, you should follow the links for Magento 2.x.

Below are some helpful links to create your first module. Please check and let me know your feedback:

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-module-in-magento-2/

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2016/04/04/magento2-helloworld-module-development-part1/

http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/